# I get this error (InputDispacher) but why?

Tags: android, android-logcat

My Android application crashes leaving this not so insightful message in LogCat:
(Information about the App:
It is supposed to become a game. One day.
In my render loop everything works fine for about 100 frames.
This problem occured since I added OpenGL methods to draw shapes.)

```
04-20 10:45:12.714: I/DEBUG(31): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
04-20 10:45:12.714: I/DEBUG(31): Build fingerprint: 'generic/sdk/generic:2.3.3/GRI34/101070:eng/test-keys'
04-20 10:45:12.714: I/DEBUG(31): pid: 950, tid: 960  >>> game.main <<<
04-20 10:45:12.714: I/DEBUG(31): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 002ba000
04-20 10:45:12.714: I/DEBUG(31):  r0 80000000  r1 ffffff99  r2 0000008e  r3 00010000
04-20 10:45:12.714: I/DEBUG(31):  r4 002b9ff8  r5 002a5300  r6 0000000e  r7 002b9ff8
04-20 10:45:12.714: I/DEBUG(31):  r8 0000000c  r9 00000012  10 00000000  fp 002a4060
04-20 10:45:12.724: I/DEBUG(31):  ip 00000029  sp 43fceae0  lr ac405980  pc ac405984  cpsr a0000010
04-20 10:45:12.824: I/DEBUG(31):          #00  pc 00005984  /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
04-20 10:45:12.824: I/DEBUG(31):          #01  pc 0000416c  /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
04-20 10:45:12.824: I/DEBUG(31):          #02  pc 00005540  /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
04-20 10:45:12.824: I/DEBUG(31):          #03  pc 000060a8  /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
04-20 10:45:12.824: I/DEBUG(31):          #04  pc 00017d74  /system/lib/libdvm.so
04-20 10:45:12.824: I/DEBUG(31): code around pc:
04-20 10:45:12.824: I/DEBUG(31): ac405964 e5920000 e1a05001 e1a04002 ebfff8f6 
04-20 10:45:12.824: I/DEBUG(31): ac405974 e5850000 e5940004 ebfff8f3 e5850004 
04-20 10:45:12.824: I/DEBUG(31): ac405984 e5940008 ebfff8f0 e5850008 e8bd8070 
04-20 10:45:12.834: I/DEBUG(31): ac405994 e92d4070 e5920000 e1a05001 e1a04002 
04-20 10:45:12.834: I/DEBUG(31): ac4059a4 ebfff8e9 e5850000 e5940004 ebfff8e6 
04-20 10:45:12.834: I/DEBUG(31): code around lr:
04-20 10:45:12.834: I/DEBUG(31): ac405960 e92d4070 e5920000 e1a05001 e1a04002 
04-20 10:45:12.834: I/DEBUG(31): ac405970 ebfff8f6 e5850000 e5940004 ebfff8f3 
04-20 10:45:12.834: I/DEBUG(31): ac405980 e5850004 e5940008 ebfff8f0 e5850008 
04-20 10:45:12.834: I/DEBUG(31): ac405990 e8bd8070 e92d4070 e5920000 e1a05001 
04-20 10:45:12.834: I/DEBUG(31): ac4059a0 e1a04002 ebfff8e9 e5850000 e5940004 
04-20 10:45:12.834: I/DEBUG(31): stack:
04-20 10:45:12.834: I/DEBUG(31):     43fceaa0  419036d8  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
04-20 10:45:12.834: I/DEBUG(31):     43fceaa4  80049123  /system/lib/libdvm.so
04-20 10:45:12.834: I/DEBUG(31):     43fceaa8  4057b168  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
04-20 10:45:12.834: I/DEBUG(31):     43fceaac  80085704  /system/lib/libdvm.so
04-20 10:45:12.834: I/DEBUG(31):     43fceab0  00000007  
04-20 10:45:12.834: I/DEBUG(31):     43fceab4  0000001c  
04-20 10:45:12.834: I/DEBUG(31):     43fceab8  002a3920  [heap]
04-20 10:45:12.834: I/DEBUG(31):     43fceabc  0000001c  
04-20 10:45:12.834: I/DEBUG(31):     43fceac0  002a3920  [heap]
04-20 10:45:12.834: I/DEBUG(31):     43fceac4  0000e810  [heap]
04-20 10:45:12.834: I/DEBUG(31):     43fceac8  002a4c00  [heap]
04-20 10:45:12.834: I/DEBUG(31):     43fceacc  00000010  
04-20 10:45:12.844: I/DEBUG(31):     43fcead0  002a5200  [heap]
04-20 10:45:12.844: I/DEBUG(31):     43fcead4  ac410788  /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
04-20 10:45:12.844: I/DEBUG(31):     43fcead8  df002777  
04-20 10:45:12.844: I/DEBUG(31):     43fceadc  e3a070ad  
04-20 10:45:12.844: I/DEBUG(31): #00 43fceae0  002a5300  [heap]
04-20 10:45:12.844: I/DEBUG(31):     43fceae4  002a3920  [heap]
04-20 10:45:12.844: I/DEBUG(31):     43fceae8  0000000e  
04-20 10:45:12.844: I/DEBUG(31):     43fceaec  ac404170  /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
04-20 10:45:12.844: I/DEBUG(31): #01 43fceaf0  00000012  
04-20 10:45:12.844: I/DEBUG(31):     43fceaf4  002a4c00  [heap]

04-20 10:45:12.844: I/DEBUG(31):     43fceaf8  002a3920  [heap]
04-20 10:45:12.844: I/DEBUG(31):     43fceafc  00000012  
04-20 10:45:12.844: I/DEBUG(31):     43fceb00  00000012  
04-20 10:45:12.844: I/DEBUG(31):     43fceb04  00000000  
04-20 10:45:12.844: I/DEBUG(31):     43fceb08  00003f3f  
04-20 10:45:12.844: I/DEBUG(31):     43fceb0c  00000542  
04-20 10:45:12.844: I/DEBUG(31):     43fceb10  442c89f7  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted)
04-20 10:45:12.844: I/DEBUG(31):     43fceb14  ac405544  /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
04-20 10:45:13.974: I/BootReceiver(61): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_00 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
04-20 10:45:14.004: D/Zygote(33): Process 950 terminated by signal (11)
04-20 10:45:14.004: E/InputDispatcher(61): channel '406bdbd0 game.main/game.main.Game (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
04-20 10:45:14.004: E/InputDispatcher(61): channel '406bdbd0 game.main/game.main.Game (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```

Comment: If you search for `"Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8"` on this site you will find that many people have encountered this error. Usually, there is no clear solution. My guess is that some native library has encountered an error which leads to problems in your app.

Comment: Hey thank you so much. I read some of the posts you mentioned. Still I can't say how to tackle this problem now.